# X86 64 bit long mode tables

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, osdev, page-tables

I have successfully entered 32 bit protected mode and wish to go to 64 bit long mode now.  I understand the code to do this but do not understand how the 64 bit tables work compared to the 32 bit GDT.  I wondered if there was a tutorial on this or an easy way to explain it or do I just have to read the AMD manual (not easy to follow).  I know the structure is

```
PML4T[0] -> PDPT.
PDPT[0] -> PDT.
PDT[0] -> PT.
PT
```

But I'm not sure how to use it.  I presume the GDT from the 32 bit mode is not used in 64 bit long mode?

Comment: Well that makes no sense. The GDT and paging both exist in 32bit and 64bit modes, and have nothing to do with each other. You do need both.

Comment: I mean that once you change to 64 bit mode and don't want to go back, the 32 bit GDT is no longer used.

Comment: OK, I see now that the GDT is used in long mode but only for the 64 bit settings.  Say I wanted to set up 2MB paging with code starting from 4MB-10MB and data from 10MB to end of memory.  How on earth do I set the PDT tables and the control registers?  It seems a little confusing in the AMD manual .......

Comment: See https://wiki.osdev.org/Setting_Up_Long_Mode#Setting_up_the_Paging and related other links on the osdev wiki like https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64#How_do_I_enable_Long_Mode_.3F.  The x86-64 page-table format is different, based on the PAE page-table format but 4 levels deep.  See [Why in 64bit the virtual address are 4 bits short (48bit long) compared with the physical address (52 bit long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152) for diagrams of the entry formats.