# What is the relationship between "64-bit operating system", "x64-based processor" to word size?

Tags: operating-system, x86-64, cpu-architecture, cpu-word

I was wondering, does a 64-bit operating system and a x64-based processor mean that the word size (i.e. memory transfer size between processor and physical memory) is 64 bits? What if the operating system is a 32-bit and processor x64? And what about x86-based processors? How do these two specifications (XX-bit operating system and xXX-based processor) relate to the actual word size in the hardware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't mean that.  modern x86 CPUs have 64-byte cache lines, and can do accesses to cache at any power-of-2 width from 1 byte up to a 32 byte SIMD vector, or 64-byte in CPUs with AVX512.  See also [How much of ‘What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory’ is still valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126311/what-every-programmer-should-know-about-memory/47714514#47714514)

**"word size" is not really a meaningful term for x86**; it's not a word-oriented ISA at all.

In Intel documentation a "word" is 16 bits, just to maintain consistency with documentation going back to 8086.  The bus and register widths in hardware are unrelated to that.

---

x86-64 has 64-bit integer registers when running in long mode (64-bit mode).  And supports 64-bit addresses.  (Actually 48 bit virtual addresses, and up to 52-bit physical depending on the hardware, because of the page table format.  [Why in x86-64 the virtual address are 4 bits shorter than physical (48 bits vs. 52 long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-64bit-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-short-48bit-long-compared-with-the))

x86 CPUs since 32-bit Pentium have been able to do 64-bit data transfers.  [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)

---

#### Related:

- [What's the size of a QWORD on a 64-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430725/whats-the-size-of-a-qword-on-a-64-bit-machine) - especially the section about how x86 is not a word-oriented ISA.
- [Are machine code instructions fetched in little endian 4-byte words on an Intel x86-64 architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229585/are-machine-code-instructions-fetched-in-little-endian-4-byte-words-on-an-intel/68229991#68229991) x86 machine-code isn't word-oriented either, unlike most RISCs where even compressed instructions are either one or two half-words.  Or traditionally were always aligned full words (32-bit, even for RISCs with 64-bit integer registers. As machines have grown, there's no longer a single "word size" that's the width of everything, because 32 bits is enough for some things.)