# Enabling segmentation on x86-64

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, x86-64, paging, virtual-memory

I'm running Ubuntu Linux on x86-64 architecture, and I want to enable segmentation (as opposed to paging).
Is there a way to use segmentation instead of paging on x86-64 based Linux systems?
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've checked a few websites like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) but haven't got much information, and searching for "enabling segmentation on Linux" or "enabling segmentation on x86-64" doesn't return much information. I actually think the first answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469253/does-linux-not-use-segmentation-but-only-paging) might mean that I can't use segmentation anymore, but am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to "enabled" segmentation on x86-64 GNU/Linux, it already uses FS for thread-local storage.  But **x86-64 segmentation is vestigial and not usable as an alternative to paging**.  The base and limit of CS/DS/ES/SS are fixed at 0 / unlimited in long mode.  It exists mostly as x86 legacy, and as a way to control what mode the CPU is executing in.  (By far jump to a CS segment descriptor with the `L` bit set for 64-bit long mode, or other bits for 32-bit vs. 16-bit compat mode.)

You could possibly write a 64-bit kernel that used segmentation for memory protection of 32-bit processes (with 1G hugepages direct-mapping all the virtual address space you use; you can't disable paging in x86-64, except for "legacy mode" using the CPU as a 32-bit-only CPU).

**Of course Linux has no support for this; it's built around a flat memory model with paging, like all modern mainstream x86 OSes.**  Using segmentation instead would fundamentally change everything about how you manage memory and get new memory from the OS.  You'd have to write a new libc at least, and rewrite a bunch of software that knows anything about paging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand that "1G hugepage for direct-mapping" you mentioned comes from the fact that x86 supports 4KB/2MB/1GB pages, but does that mean I'll need 4 of 1G hugepages to map a whole 32bit memory address?

Comment: @WannabeArchitect: Yes.  Note that only PAE / x86-64 page tables use 4k/2M/1G pages ([9 bits per level, 8-byte PTEs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152)); legacy 32-bit mode kernels not using PAE have 4k/4M pages (10 bits per level, 4 byte PTEs), with no option of covering the entire address space with a single 4G page.  (You just disable paging if you want that.)