# How did offset of an array come to mean the starting address of an array

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, terminology, memory-address

consider the assembly code - `mov edi, offset newarray` 
As per what I have read this will put the address of `newarray` into the register `edi`
What I don't understand is this term `offset` how does the English meaning of this term
fits here.

Comment: `offset` is the distance from the start of the segment. Under typical circumstances the base address is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

x86 memory addresses are of the form `segment:offset`, where the offset part is in a normal (general purpose) register like EDI (or RDI in 64-bit code).

In modern systems where we use a flat memory model, the `segment` base is always 0, and the `offset` *is* the whole address, equal to the linear address.

x86-64 addressing for `mov eax, [rdi + rax*4 + 1234]`:

- RDI is the *base register* in the *[addressing mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes)*.

  - RAX is the *index* (because it has the scale factor, or the 2nd register in `[rdi+rax]`)
  - 1234 is the displacement, encoded as a dword (disp32) sign-extended to 64-bit
- `RDI + RAX*4 + 1234` is the *effective address* calculated by that addressing mode.  (Hence `lea eax, fs:[rdi + rax*4 + 1234]` gives you that, even if the FS segment base is non-zero.)  This is the **offset** part of the seg:off address.
- RDI as the base register implies the DS segment.  The `seg:off` -> *linear address* is `DS_base + offset`.  (Which equals the offset because the CS, DS, ES, and SS bases are fixed to 0 in 64-bit mode, and in 32-bit mode mainstream OSes set them to 0.)
- The linear address is a *virtual address* because 64-bit mode requires that paging is enabled.
- virt->phys translation happens by looking up the page-number part (the bits above the bottom 12) in the page tables, cached by the TLB.  ([Why in x86-64 the virtual address are 4 bits shorter than physical (48 bits vs. 52 long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152)).  The resulting physical address is used to access memory (via the cache), or MMIO over PCIe if the phys address is a device address.

So yes, to index an array, you want RDI = `OFFSET my_array` in MASM syntax.  (Of course in 64-bit mode you'd want a RIP-relative LEA like `lea rdi, [my_array]`, but in 32-bit mode yes you'd do `mov edi, OFFSET my_array`.)

---

The OS takes care of making sure the segment base address is `0` for CS, DS, ES, and SS, so `[ebx]` and `[ebp]` access the same linear address when EBX = EBP.  (implicit DS vs. SS segments implied by using EBX or EBP as the base register for the addressing mode.)

And that `call ebx` would fetch code from the same memory address you could read or write with `mov dword ptr [ebx], 0C3909090`  (3x nop + ret).

---

**Legacy 16-bit real-mode mode code often does need to make sure the DS segment base is set to match the start of the data section.** Or *a* data section in a large program.**  (In real mode, `mov ds, ax` writing to a segment register sets the base = `value<<4`, instead of using the value as a selector indexing [the GDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table) or LDT.)

For example, DOS `.exe` programs often started with

```
PROC main
   mov ax, @data       ; segment for the data section
   mov ds, ax
   mov es, ax

  mov  bx, OFFSET other_var
  mov  ax, [bx]         ; relies on DS being set properly

  mov  [some_var], ax   ; also relies on DS; uses the offset of some_var in the addressing mode.
  ...
```

You could `mov bx, OFFSET some_var` before setting DS, and dereference it after.  The segment and offset parts are independent.

Similarly, legacy BIOS MBR bootloaders need to set DS to match the `org` value they assume, otherwise they access the wrong place in memory.

Real-mode programs with more than 64k of data would need multiple segments, and have to switch DS or ES to use them.  This was generally inconvenient compared to having universal 32-bit pointers that any code could use efficiently, and x86-16 is pretty thoroughly obsolete, so it's rare for people to write new programs that actually use x86 segmentation for anything.
If you want lots of memory, it's much easier to write 32-bit or 64-bit code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not rare to see assembly newbies here on SO to start with `x86-16`. I guess their **teachers should be blamed**, they probably believe that 32bit/64bit code is twice/four times more difficult than 16bit.

Comment: @vitsoft: Agreed. But at least their teachers don't usually make them write programs that deal with more than 64k of data, so they don't actually need far pointers and "huge" memory models.  So that makes learning about segmentation just a pointless extra complication that gets taught along with assembly in general (which is hard enough for many beginners to wrap their heads around even when asm pointers are just C pointers.)

Comment: It's unfortunately not rare for people to mess around with 16-bit code (especially hobby bootloaders, but yeah also homework), but actually using segmentation any more than just setting it up once, or for writing to video RAM, is not something we see SO questions about.