# Is the sentence below in "MASM Version 6.1 Programmer's Guide" correct for Windows NT?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, 32-bit, memory-segmentation

[MASM Version 6.1 Programmer's Guide](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/450367/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf) says the following in its page number 12:

> Segmented addressing refers to the internal mechanism that combines a
> segment value and an offset value to form a complete memory address.
> The two parts of an address are represented as
>
> *segment:offset*
>
> **The segment portion always consists of a 16-bit value**. The offset portion is a 16-bit value in 16-bit mode or a 32-bit value in 32-bit
> mode.

I don't think the highlighted text above is correct for Windows NT, a 32-bit system.

**Edit**:

As can be seen from the comments below, there are currently two opposing positions held by @Cody Gray and @Raymond Chen, which certainly weren't even addressed in the other 3 questions, from which mine was considered a duplicate.

Comment: No, segment:offset addressing does not apply to 32-bit flat mode.

Comment: @CodyGray See the last row on Table 1.2 in page 10 of the book. It mentions "Segment selectors" for Windows NT.  Is this also wrong?

Comment: The sentence is correct, but is not useful in Windows NT because all the selectors set their base address to 0.

Comment: Quoting from the paragraph in that same section: *"Windows NT uses the so-called “flat model” of 80386/486 processors. This model places the processor’s entire address space within one 32-bit segment. The section “Defining Basic Attributes with .MODEL” in Chapter 2 explains how to use the flat model. In flat model, your program can (in theory) access up to 4 gigabytes of virtual memory. Since code, data, and stack reside in the same segment, each segment register can hold the same value, which need never change. "*

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for your replies. I'll assume that the sentence highlighted above and the use of the expression "Segment selectors" in Table 1.2 referring to Windows NT are both wrong.

Comment: The sentences are not wrong. They are still correct, but not particularly useful since most segments are flat. However, it is still important when dealing with the `fs` selector register.

Comment: Cody's comment is an oversimplification.  x86 memory addressing is *always* seg:off, but the mapping to linear is usually trivial outside of 16-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you tell me how the "segment portion always consists of a 16-bit value" in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Segment registers are 16 bits wide, always, regardless of mode.  (Their meaning is completely different in protected mode vs. real mode, though: indexes into the GDT / LDT instead of being a shifted segment-base directly.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386#Architecture has a diagram of the registers.  I think [How did offset of an array come to mean the starting address of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68002064) is a better duplicate.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso See the definition of pointer [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386#Data_types)

Comment: @CodyGray, I think this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/10810203/2945027 should be added in duplicates list to fully address the issue of "flat model, but FS is still there"