# x86 address space calculation PAE to 36 bits

Tags: memory-management, x86, paging, memory-address, page-tables

I'm having some hard time understanding PAE. I know it creates a 3rd level of indirection via the PDPT, so that the address translation goes from CR3 -> PDPT(4 entries) -> PD(512 entries) -> PT (512 entries) -> PAGE (4096). But the address is still 32 bits, how do you get 36 bit addresses from this scheme? I'd appreciate an example. How does adding another table "increases" the address space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAE changes nothing about 32-bit virtual addresses, only the size of physical address they're mapped to.  (Which sucks a lot, nowhere near enough virtual address space to map all those physical pages at once.  Linus Torvalds wrote a nice rant about PAE: https://cl4ssic4l.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/linus-torvalds-about-pae/ originally posted on https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=76912&curpostid=76973 / https://www.realworldtech.com/forum/?threadid=76912&curpostid=76980)

It also widens a PTE (Page Table Entry) from 4 bytes to 8 bytes, which means 2 levels aren't enough anymore; *that's* where the small extra level comes to translate the top 2 bits of virtual addresses via those 4 entries.

**36-bit only happened to be the supported physical address size in the first generation of CPUs that implemented PAE, Pentium Pro**  There is no inherent 36-bit limit to PAE.

x86-64 adopted the PTE format, which [has room for up to 52-bit physical addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509152/why-in-x86-64-the-virtual-address-are-4-bits-shorter-than-physical-48-bits-vs).  Current x86-64 CPUs support the same physical address-size in legacy mode with PAE as they do in 64-bit mode.  (As reported by CPUID).  That limit is a design choice that saves bits in cache tags, TLB entries, store-buffer entries, etc. and in comparators involved with them.  It's normally chosen to be more than the amount of RAM that a real system could actually use, given the commercially available DIMM sizes and number of memory controllers even in multi-socket systems, and still leave room for some I/O address space.

x86-64 came soon after PAE, or soon enough for desktop use to be relevant, so it's a common misconception that PAE is only 36 bits.  (Because 64-bit mode is a vastly better way to address more memory, allowing a single process to use more than 2G or 3G depending on user/kernel split.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes so the 36 bit thingy is more related to the physical address bus than to the paging scheme itself?

Comment: @Alexey: Not just buses, also the number of physical address bits in cache tags, TLB entries, and store buffer entries.  There isn't necessarily an actual physical address "bus" that's 36 bits wide, although Intel used a frontside bus between CPU and chipset until Nehalem integrated memory controllers.  IDK what format it used for sending addresses. Pentium Pro may also SDRAM I think, but SDRAM (including modern DDR4) uses a memory address bus with split row/column addressing multiplexed over fewer address lines.  So on modern CPUs there isn't an *external* address bus of that width.