# Understanding paging and fetching instructions from memory

Tags: emulation, cpu-architecture, paging, page-tables, virtual-address-space

as stated in the title, I am implementing a processor emulator in C# and I have a problem with understanding, that is, with the paging logic when retrieving an instruction from memory.

Namely, I have a 64-bit address space and in the program I specify an arbitrary number of addresses, for example 1000, where each address is 64 bits long.My first problem in understanding is, when I create an instruction and when I add it to the memory, should I add it to a physical or a virtual address?

That 64-bit address is divided, with the last 12 bits being reserved for the offset and the remaining bits being used for paging tables. For example, let's say we have 4 paging levels, the first 9 bits are used for the level 4 paging table (we'll start from the bottom), the next 9 bits are used for the level 3 paging table, and so on until we reach the level 1 paging table that has access to the physical address.

What I don't understand here is what is obtained by going through these paging tables and how do we get the physical address from the virtual address, do I have to specify both physical and virtual addresses at the beginning of the program and map one to the other? I don't understand that going through those pagination tables, what am I even getting with that?

What is the situation with the program counter, does it contain a physical address or that virtual address? In order for the instruction to be fetched and executed, do I need to have a physical or virtual address in the program counter? If someone is willing to explain the principle of paging to me with an example, how would I understand how I should realize the implementation?

For example, let me have a 64-bit address: 0x0001234FFFFADE09, how can I find it on a concrete example. Is E09 an offset and the rest a paging table? And then what is 000 for the level 4 paging table and so I move on? But then how do I get a physical address based on this address, did I specify that physical address somewhere, I'm quite confused.

Comment: Your paging scheme matches x86-64, so look for examples of that.  You give the CPU the physical address of a topl-level PML4 table.  Given that, it can translate any virtual address to physical, or find that the virtual page is not-present. ([Why in x86-64 the virtual address are 4 bits shorter than physical (48 bits vs. 52 long)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46509152) has a diagram)  Page tables are a radix tree which can be sparse for unused parts of the address-space, where virtual page addresses are the keys, and physical page addresses are the values in the leaf nodes.

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging may also be useful.

Comment: Re: adding instructions to memory: are you talking about something like a MARS / RARS IDE with a built-in assembler and emulator?  You don't need or want paging for that, unless you're running "guest" code that can actually manipulate the page tables.  You just want a couple extents (memory regions) with start/end addresses, one for each section (.text / .data / .bss / .rodata etc) that the guest code uses, or ELF segment if you're assembling + linking to make an actual executable.